# My Answer keep Returning Wrong after First input and wont keep track of score?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, awt

I trying to make a math quiz game that generates random question and keep track of of what question are wrong and write.

got action listener to work but when i type in a answer it say my answer is wrong, even though it right. the first question that appear work fine but after that it , it say all my answer are wrong even though they are right and keep track of  score.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
        import javax.swing.*;
        import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

        import java.util.Random;
        import java.util.Scanner;
        import java.awt.*;
        import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
        import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

        public class PracticeMath extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
            Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
            Random generator = new Random();
            protected JButton excerciseButton = new JButton( "New Excerices" ); // start new quiz session
            protected JButton answerButton = new JButton( "Answer" ); // set new question, check if the answer correct or wrong
            protected JLabel titlelabel = new JLabel( "How much is: " ); 
            protected int correctcounter = 0; // keep track of correct answer
            protected int wrongcounter = 0; // keep track of wrong answer
            protected int one = generator.nextInt(10);//generate ranodm first number of question
            protected int two = generator.nextInt(10); // generate random second number of question
            protected int i = generator.nextInt(4); // generate random operator
            protected char[] ops = { '+', '-', '/', '*' }; // the math operator
            protected JLabel correctlabel = new JLabel(" Number of Correct Answer: ");
            protected JLabel wronglabel = new JLabel( " Number of  Wrong answers:  " );
            protected JLabel firstnum = new JLabel("" + one); // display first number
            protected JLabel secondnum = new JLabel("" + two); //  display second number
            protected JLabel randomOP = new JLabel("" + ops[i]); // display operator
            protected JLabel equalOP = new JLabel("=");
            protected JTextField answerText = new JTextField(); //text area for writing you answer
            protected JLabel questionmark = new JLabel("?");
            protected JLabel correct = new JLabel(""+ correctcounter); // display correct answer
            protected JLabel wrong = new JLabel(""+ wrongcounter); // display wrong answer
            protected JLabel commentlabel = new JLabel(""); // set a comment for how good you doing. optionial




            public PracticeMath(){

                answerText.setColumns(5);

                JPanel Panel1 = new JPanel();// add a panel
                FlowLayout flowLayout = (FlowLayout) Panel1.getLayout();// layout for panel
                getContentPane().setLayout( new FlowLayout( FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5)); // set layout
                getContentPane().add(Panel1); // set panel
                titlelabel.setForeground(Color.ORANGE); 
                titlelabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 25));

                Panel1.add(titlelabel);
                firstnum.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                Panel1.add(firstnum);

                randomOP.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 25));
                Panel1.add(randomOP);

                secondnum.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));

                Panel1.add(secondnum);

                equalOP.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                Panel1.add(equalOP);

                Panel1.add(answerText);

                questionmark.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                Panel1.add(questionmark);

                Panel1.add(commentlabel);



                JPanel Panel3 = new JPanel();
                FlowLayout flowLayout3 = (FlowLayout) Panel3.getLayout();
                flowLayout3.setHgap(15);
                getContentPane().setLayout( new FlowLayout( FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));
                getContentPane().add(Panel3);
                Panel3.add(excerciseButton);
                Panel3.add(answerButton);



                    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
                panel2.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Statistic"));
                getContentPane().add(panel2);
                panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 0, 0));
                panel2.add(correctlabel);
                panel2.add(wronglabel);
                correct.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                correct.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 25));
                panel2.add(correct);

                wrong.setForeground(Color.RED);
                wrong.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 25));
                panel2.add(wrong);




            answerButton.addActionListener( this );

            }






           public static void main(String[] args) {

                PracticeMath frame = new PracticeMath();
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(400,400);
                frame.setTitle( "Math Practice");
                frame.setVisible(true);





            }

         public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae )
   {
       String answer = answerText.getText();
       int answerint = Integer.parseInt(answer);
       if(one + two == answerint){
            correctcounter++;
            System.out.println("correct");
            firstnum.setText("" + generator.nextInt(11));
               randomOP.setText("" + ops[generator.nextInt(4)]);
               secondnum.setText("" + generator.nextInt(11));


        }
       else if(one-two == answerint){
            correctcounter++;
            System.out.println("correct");
            firstnum.setText("" + generator.nextInt(11));
               randomOP.setText("" + ops[generator.nextInt(4)]);
               secondnum.setText("" + generator.nextInt(11));
        }
        else if(one * two ==answerint){
            correctcounter++;
            System.out.println("correct");
            firstnum.setText("" + generator.nextInt(11));
               randomOP.setText("" + ops[generator.nextInt(4)]);
               secondnum.setText("" + generator.nextInt(11));
        }else if(one/two == answerint){
            correctcounter++;
            System.out.println("correct");
            firstnum.setText("" + generator.nextInt(11));
               randomOP.setText("" + ops[generator.nextInt(4)]);
               secondnum.setText("" + generator.nextInt(11));
        }
        else{
            wrongcounter++;
            System.out.println("wrong");
            firstnum.setText("" + generator.nextInt(11));
               randomOP.setText("" + ops[generator.nextInt(4)]);
               secondnum.setText("" + generator.nextInt(11));
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is that generated code? Can you mark the parts that you did write?

Comment: I can't even understand it.. the statistics don't work

Comment: that strange everything work fine on myside except for the problem i having

Comment: generator.nextInt(4) will generate a number 0 through 4. Is that what you were expecting? generator.nextInt(10) will generate a number 0 through 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never reassign the variables `one` and `two`, so they are still using the same values they started with...

Try re-structuring your `actionPerformed` method to reduce the code duplication and assign the new equation values to the `one` and `two` variables....

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    String answer = answerText.getText();
    int answerint = Integer.parseInt(answer);
    if (one + two == answerint) {
        correctcounter++;
        System.out.println("correct");
    } else if (one - two == answerint) {
        correctcounter++;
        System.out.println("correct");
    } else if (one * two == answerint) {
        correctcounter++;
        System.out.println("correct");
    } else if (one / two == answerint) {
        correctcounter++;
        System.out.println("correct");
    } else {
        wrongcounter++;
        System.out.println("wrong");
    }
    one = generator.nextInt(11);
    two = generator.nextInt(11);
    firstnum.setText("" + one);
    randomOP.setText("" + ops[generator.nextInt(4)]);
    secondnum.setText("" + two);
}
```

**Updated**

While you are maintaining a counter of the right and wrong answers, you are not displaying them any where (freaked me out the first time I run the program).

At the bottom of the `actionPerformed` method, you need to update the labels displaying the number of right and wrong answers.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    // ... Previous content... //

    correct.setText(Integer.toString(correctcounter));
    wrong.setText(Integer.toString(wrongcounter));
}
```

Comment: but i still not able to keep track of score =(

Comment: In the body of the `else if (one - two == answerint)` conditional you're still setting the text fields to new random values, which is now done at the bottom of the method.

Comment: @ajmccluskey Sorry my bad, missed that piece of code. Fixed now

Comment: @DevendraDannyRamdayal What do you mean?  Each if statement is evaluted individually and the score is maintained (using `correctcounter` and `wrongcounter`) all we've done is move the repeated regeneration of the next question to the bottom of the `actionPerformed` method (and assigned the new equation values)

Comment: the counter are not changing on my gui they just stay at zero

Comment: @DevendraDannyRamdayal Check update (I hoped that was the problem)

Comment: OK it work. but now i have another problem, if i answer a question right it add 1 to correct side but if i answer a question wrong it one away from the correct side and then add one to wrong side.i will like to keep track of both side

Comment: i've  tryed everything so far. i still not able to keep track of the score

Comment: nevermind  found the problem code work now thank for all your help

Answer (score 1):

In `actionPerformed`, it appears you're updating the text fields (`firstnum` and `secondnum`) with new random values after each question is answered, but you're checking the answer using the variables `one` and `two`.  As `one` and `two` aren't updated with the random values being displayed, they become out of sync with what is displayed after you've answered the first question.

Comment: ok i will able to figure out how to fix my answer issue but im still now sure how to keep track of score?

Comment: I would use MadProgrammer's suggested code modifications. Once you've updated your correct/wrong counts, you should update the text for their corresponding labels. I haven't done Swing in a while, but you may need to repaint the GUI after that as well.